# How to preserve context in JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have a job as under

```
public class MyPeriodicJob extends JobService{
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

        // do something (but context is needed)

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It is started in MainActivity

```
private void scheduleJob(){
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,
                MyPeriodicJob.class);

        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
                .setPeriodic(86400000)
                .setPersisted(true).build();
        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    }
```

The device may restart but the job is expected to persist. How can I pass context (which must persist) to the `MyPeriodicJob` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job service is the child of Service class, so you don't need to pass the context, anywhere because it's already there. Service class itself belongs to ContextWrapper which belongs to Context. So just use `this.(CONTEXT FUNCTION YOU NEED`)

Comment: Man you're too good. I was needing context as I wanted to create a notification (channel created earlier). This notification requires context. Now that I have it, I am good to go. Thanks. You made my day!